# calculation of allele frequency using wig file in R

Tags: r

- I have a matrix(similar to a wig file) like this:

  ```
  Position reference A C G T N sum(total read counts)
  68773265 A 1 0 0 0 0   1 
  68773266 C 0 1 0 1 0   2
  68773267 C 0 1 1 2 0   4
  ```
- To achieve variant(non-reference) allele ratio,

I want to create this: `(sum-reference sequence's count)/sum * 100`  per position

```
   Position reference frequency(%) sum(total read counts) 
   68773265 A  0 1
   68773266 C 50 2
   68773267 C 75 4
```

Please give me some advice on this problem. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the subset of column names "nm1", `match` the "reference" column with the "nm1" to get the column index, `cbind` with `1:nrow(df1)` for creating row/column index.  Get the `rowSums` of "nm1" columns ("Sum1"), use this to create "frequencyPercent" based on the formula in the post.

```
nm1 <- c('A', 'C', 'G', 'T') # this could include `N` also
indx <- cbind(1:nrow(df1), match(df1$reference, nm1))
Sum1 <- rowSums(df1[nm1])
data.frame(df1[1:2], frequencyPercent=100*(Sum1-df1[nm1][indx])/Sum1, 
          SumTotalCounts=df1[,ncol(df1)])
```

Or use `transform` on the original dataset

```
 transform(df1, frequencyPercent=100*(Sum1-df1[nm1][indx])/Sum1,
        check.names=FALSE)[c(1:2,8:9)]
 #   Position reference sum(total read counts) frequencyPercent
 #1 68773265         A                      1         0
 #2 68773266         C                      2        50
 #3 68773267         C                      4        75
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Position = 68773265:68773267, reference = c("A", 
"C", "C"), A = c(1L, 0L, 0L), C = c(0L, 1L, 1L), G = c(0L, 0L, 
1L), T = 0:2, N = c(0L, 0L, 0L), `sum(total read counts)` = c(1L, 
2L, 4L)), .Names = c("Position", "reference", "A", "C", "G", 
"T", "N", "sum(total read counts)"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```